# Windows Service - OnSessionChange - Slow Notification

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, winlogon

I am writing a Windows Service that needs to detect when there are any user session changes on  the machine (i.e. a user logs on, logs off, disconnects, etc). I have implemented the `OnSessionChange` override method within my code and I have noticed that there can be delays of anywhere up to a minute between the user's session changing (for any reason) and the service receiving the notification. I am currently just printing the current date/time and the `changeDescription` reason to a text file to eliminate any delays my code may be adding.

My question is, is this behavior expected - substantial delays between when the session changes and when the service is notified? If it is, can any one suggest a better (quicker) method for being notified when any user session changes?

Comment: Side note: please eidt your user name instead adding signature.

Comment: @user1973399, I know this is an old post but did you ever get to the bottom of the OnSessionChange notification delay?  I'm experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well.. please post up an answer if you have one !